# Can't open SqlConnection to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I'm new to asp.net and I was trying to make a simple login page that will search the username and password entered in a database. I created the `App_Data` folder and I have database in it called `Database1.mdf`. Inside that database there is a table called `users`.

This  is the code behind the login page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string mcn = Request.Form["username"];
        string pass = Request.Form["pass"];
        string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mcn = '" + mcn + "' AND pass = '" + pass + "'";
        string connectionstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
        bool found;
        found = (bool)data.Read();
        con.Close();

        if (found)
        {
            Session["user"] = true; 
        }

        Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
    }
 }
```

When I run the page and submit the login form which calls this `Page_Load` I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database
>   for file App_Data\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC
>   share.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **This query is open to Sql Injection attacks.** Please parameterize it. Furthermore, you should be disposing of your objects. I see you call `con.Close()` but most of these support disposal. Wrap your `SqlConnection`, `SqlDataAdapter`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` in `using` statements.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you've elected against use of a more stable framework, for instance ASP Identity? And is there a reason you're doing this in the Page_Load when a PostBack is occurring, as compared to on the Button_Click event that is likely bringing you here? This will cause any buttons on the page to attempt a login, which will likely confuse everyone.

Comment: I think you could fix your connection string with `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Module.mdf`, however everything that @MatthewHaugen said is absolutely true and need to be fixed ASAP (And revert the condition to `!IsPostBack`)

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your comment. I changed the attachdbfilename to |DataDirectory|\database1.mdf but now I get this error: **An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.**

Comment: What is `users` in your SELECT statement?  You said you had a table called `Table`.  Is `users` a Stored Procedure?  If so, that might be where your incorrect syntax is.

Comment: @ppittle I also have a table called users, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally fixed it just by moving everything to a different class. This made everything very organized and I think that as a beginner it was hard to look at it and find what was probably a syntax error.

Thanks for the comments!